# is it possible to send a data when a websocket connection is opened

Tags: html, websocket, jetty-8

I am implementing a Jetty Websocket servlet. 
When the server receives a new connection, I want to send a message that will be read by websocket's onopen function. I want this message to be sent only during the open and not using the regular connection.SendMessage() function. Is it possible to do that? and how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no support for this in the protocol but you could fudge something yourself.

- When your server completes a handshake, store the initial message you want to deliver to a client.
- In your client's `onopen` function, send a "read initial message" request.
- In your server, check that this client hasn't read its initial message; respond with the message; set a flag saying that the initial message has been sent.
- Your client and server are both now free to send other messages.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I may have missed something when searching online. I'll follow the approach you have suggested.

Comment: It's ridiculous that this isn't in the protocol... but hey ho. The above sounds the most sensible given the situation.

Answer (score 71):

Don't forget the query string. It's valid in WebSocket url.

```
new Websocket('ws://yoursite.com/path?a=1&b=2&c=3')
```

Then you can easily parse this url on server side to retrieve the data.

Comment: ya but how do you parse the url on the server side? where is the url itself made available?

Comment: should probably also mention the option of a @PathParam... see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559260/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-the-onopen-method-with-jee7-websockets)

Comment: I found it!  I consoled out the `req` from here: `wss.on('connection', (ctx, req) => {` and I saw this in the big list of parameters: ` url: '/?/resolution=1920x1080',` which was my query string i appended to the original url over on the client.